# Achievement missing; upvote not listed

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

My achievements box is missing one upvote I received today. This is probably just a temporary glitch, but in case it is something more endemic I'm reporting it anyway.

At the time of this question, I got 15 upvotes and two accepts (180 points), but my achievement box reports only 14 upvotes (170):

[image: achievements vs. weekly points]

The missing item is the Flask answer I gave late last night; only one vote shows in the achievements box:

[image: Flask at one upvote]

But my reputation tab shows there are in fact two upvotes:

[image: Reputation tab so far]

The [answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098318/flask-background-thread-sees-a-non-empty-queue-as-empty/24101692#24101692) shows no anomalies that I can detect.

The mobile web version of the reputation tab shows the votes were cast at 2:32 and 5:38; the first vote was also the very first vote I received today. The achievements box reports that first vote, by the looks of it, as it is listed *below* the second post to receive an upvote today.

Comment: I can confirm the problem. In my achievements pop-up, one "accept" is missing today, and one "upvote" yesterday. In the reputation tab everything looks ok.

Comment: It happened yesterday for me as well; until late in the day one upvote was missing. Yesterday the Redis servers were upgraded; it is most likely related to that.